# Python How to edit bot old message

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

How to edit old message sent by bot with message Id.

Example: If i use below `!ping` command it reply's `Pong`

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    msg = "Pong {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)
```

If i want to edit that message by command:
example: if i use `!editmessage MessageID` command it asks what message need to be replaced then if we type `PongPong` it edit old message `Pong` with `PongPong`

Comment: Do you know what channel the message is in?  I believe that there's no guarantee that message ids are unique across servers and channels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the message using [`get_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_message) if you know the channel it was in, then use [`wait_for_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for_message) to get the new message text.  Then use [`edit_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.edit_message) to change the message to have the new text.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def editmessage(ctx, channel: discord.Channel, *, message_id):
    try:
        message = await bot.get_message(channel, message_id)
    except discord.NotFound as e:
        await bot.say("Could not find that message")
        raise e
    await bot.say("What would you like to change the message to?")
    new_text = await bot.wait_for_message(author=ctx.message.author, channel=ctx.message.channel)
    await bot.edit_message(message, new_text.content)
```

Invoking this command would look something like

```
!editmessage #general 5678
```

Answer (score -3):

Did you read the [Discord.py-rewrite](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#message) documentation?

Message class has a method `.edit()`, so, do that:

```
import asyncio # needed for sleep that won't block the bot, only for this example

...

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    message = await bot.say(content="Ping") # send message, say() returns message sent
    await asyncio.sleep(1)                  # pause for this demo
    await message.edit(content="Pong")      # edit the previous message
```

Same way you should be able to read the documentation, figure out how to get the message by ID, then call `await message.edit(content="Something new here")`.

Comment: This question is not about [tag:discord.py-rewrite].  One way to tell is that `bot.say` isn't available in rewrite, having been replaced with the `Sendable` abc.